# Can I have multiple image backup?

Tags: windows, backup

I am using the image backup feature in windows 8.1 to create a backup of my system. However. If I try to create a new one, the first one is overwritten. So i create a new one, rename it and create a second one. However, when I want to restore an image, I have only one image avaiable, the image that is not renamed.

So my doubt is, can I have multiple images on windows 8.1?

thank so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use might be better off trying to use a 3rd party application which has many features like full system image backup or backup of a specific folder or drive. I would recommend Acronic True Image.